# How to set an object to null

Tags: postgresql

How to set an object to null.

Ex:

my object samp contains three fileds
samp.field1,samp.field2.sampfield3

If i set samp:= null;
im getting errors is there a way to set the object value to null.

Comment: What object are you talking about? Pg doesn't have "objects". Notation := comes from PL/pgSQL, so perhaps you're talking about variables in PL/pgSQL? Show us the code that generates error, and the error itself - maybe we can help then.

Answer (score 1):

An sql database does not know about objects, it deals with rows in table.

To remove a row use DELETE :

e.g. :

```
DELETE FROM samp WHERE id = 12345;

DELETE FROM samp WHERE field1 = 'Delete Me';
```

The first example is typical to remove individual rows uing their primary key (id in this case)

The second example will remove a group of rows which have a speciic value for a field.